# Find out what /dev/cuaU maps to?

Tags: freebsd, modem, 3g, pfsense

I have an USB 3G modem (Huawei E353-u2) on pfSense 2.0.2 (which is based on FreeBSD 8.1-RELEASE-p13), it seems to create 2 /dev/cuaU devices:

```
/dev/cuaU0.0
/dev/cuaU0.3
```

1) Why are there 2 devices? Is one of them maybe the usb mass storage of the stick?

2) On the OS level (shell), how can I find out which of those 2 devices is the "real modem" / to what /dev/cuaUx.y is mapped?

Thanks for any hint :-)

Comment: `dmesg | grep cua` tells you what? ;) . If you know the manufacturer you could grep for it too: `dmesg | grep -i Huawei `...

Answer (score 3):

The CUA devices are both serial ports. 3G modems have often 1 to 3 serial ports. One of them is the **communication** port and the rest are control and monitor ports that you can use for e.g. checking the signal level (with AT commands) while connected.

**The first port is *almost* always the communication port that you should use.**

You can see if `dmesg` gives any hint on which port is which, but most likely only the modem knows and Huawei won't tell.

Answer (score 1):

Web search suggests this modem knows AT command set, so you can easily check this using "tip" or "cu" commands with both ports and detect which one responds to AT.